# Nomear Variáveis com base em lista (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for, ipython-notebook

A ideia é transformar varias listas de format list para text. E nomear esse texto com o mesmo nome da lista.

O último passo "print(lista)" deve retornar o mesmo dado da da lista porém, em formato de texto. Ou seja, o resultado esperado são dois Str com o mesmo nome e conteudo das listas nomeadas: frutas e bebidas

```
**frutas = ["Banana","Uva"]
bebidas = ["Agua","Suco"]

list_names = [frutas,bebidas]

for lista in list_names:
  nome_str = lista #identifica qual deve ser o nome da var string criada
  vars()[nome_str]  = ','.join(lista)
  print(lista) #faz o print do var string criada**
```

Alguém poderia ajudar? Não estou conseguindo encontrar solução :(

O Resultado deve ser o seguinte:

o último passo deverá retornar dois print das variáveis de texto criadas a partir do For

1)

print(frutas)

Result: (formato string)

Banana,Uva

2)

print (bebidas)

Result: (formato string)

Agua,Suco

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como gostaria que fosse o resultado? Pela descrição não ficou claro.

Comment: Claro, por exemplo o print(frutas) deve retornar o mesmo conteudo que a lista frutras, porém em texto, ficando assim:  Banana,Uva

Comment: O `','.join(lista)` já não faz isso?

Comment: Ele faz a transformação mas preciso nomear esse string criado pelo .Join com o mesmo nome da lista

Comment: Ao invés de criar variáveis dinâmicas use um dicionário.

Answer (score -3):

Você quer algo desse tipo:

```
frutas = ["Banana","Uva"]
bebidas = ["Agua", "Suco"]

list_names = [frutas, bebidas]

for lista in list_names:

  var_name = [key for key, value in locals().items() if value == lista][0]  

  #irá substituir a lista por seu equivalente em string
  #ex: frutas = ["Banana","Uva"] se tornará frutas = "Banana,Uva"
  locals()[var_name] = ','.join(lista)

  print(var_name)
  print(f"Result: {locals()[var_name]}")
```